# error as "No such table" while inserting data in to table

Tags: android

Getting Error as NO such table,Table is not creating,Please help me with your answers.I think error is database.java file.So I uploaded it.In inserting values I am not changing fields of phone number into long...As I taken it as TEXT datatype in Database file.
           '

```
               public class MyDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

          Context c;

         // Database Name
           public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "BIRLA_ACCOUNTS";
        //Table Name
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "MASTERACCOUNTS";
        //  Table Columns names
        public static final String CODE = "CODE";
        public static final String NAME = "NAME";
        public static final String TYPE = "TYPE";
        public static final String ADD1 = "ADD1";
        public static final String ADD2 = "ADD2";
        public static final String CITY = "CITY";
        public static final String COUNTRY = "COUNTRY";
        public static final String PHONENO = "PHONENO";
        public static final String CONTACTPERSON = "CONTACTPERSON";
         public static final String EMAILID = "EMAILID";
        public static final String FAX = "FAX";
         public static final String TNO = "TNO";
        public static final String CSTNO = "CSTNO";
        public static final String GSTNO = "GSTNO";
        public static final String SERVICENO = "SERVICENO";

        public MyDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
        c = context;

       }

         @Override
          public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
          try {

            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+"("+CODE+" INTEGER                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
                     AUTOINCREMENT,"+NAME+" TEXT PRIMARY KEY ,"+TYPE+" TEXT,  
                       "+ADD1+" TEXT,"+ADD2+" TEXT,"+CITY+" TEXT,"+COUNTRY+                                                                                                                                                                                 
                          " TEXT,"+PHONENO+" TEXT,"
                    +CONTACTPERSON+" TEXT,"+EMAILID +" VARCHAR(50),"+FAX+" 
                        REAL,"+TNO+" REAL,"+CSTNO+" REAL,"+GSTNO+" REAL,"                                                                                                                          
            +SERVICENO +" REAL)");
              Toast.makeText(c, "Table Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                  Log.e("AccountsMaster creation", "" + e);
                       }


                  }

               @Override
          public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,
                   int  newVersion) {
            // Drop older table if existed
                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_NAME);
             // Creating tables again
                 onCreate(db);
              }
```

`

Comment: post logcat please .read http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: try uninstalling app and reinstalling

Comment: for your sanity it would be better **do not read androidhive's "tutorials"**

Comment: I tried by uninstalling app ...but it doesn't worked @Mr.Aravindraj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Rectify Your Query** . Aware from **`Blank Space`** and **`Single-Double Quote`** .

```
 "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ("
                    + CODE + " INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT ," 
                    + NAME + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY ,"
                    + TYPE + " TEXT ,"
                    + ADD1 + " TEXT ,"
                    + ADD2 + " TEXT ,"
                    + CITY + " TEXT ,"
                    + COUNTRY + " TEXT ,"
                    + PHONENO + " TEXT ,"
                    + CONTACTPERSON + " TEXT ,"
                    + EMAILID + " VARCHAR(50) ,"
                    + FAX + " REAL ,"
                    + TNO + " REAL ,"
                    + CSTNO + " REAL ,"
                    + GSTNO + " REAL ,"
                    + SERVICENO + " REAL" + ")";
```

**FYI**

Use **`INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`** in **CODE** *Field*

```
 + CODE + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ," 
 + NAME + " TEXT ,"
```

Comment: Error is "No Such Table" while inserting values..Here table is not creating.So am getting that error@IntelliJ Amiya

Comment: @Devika Uninstall old app and run again

Comment: I got It.For every change in Query.Have to  uninstall and re-install app,then it's working.Thanks @IntelliJ Amiya

Comment: @Devika Yes ... FYI You can avoid this way by using `onUpgrade Method`

Answer (score 0):

[image]instead of AUTOINCREMENT Use AUTO_INCREMENT

Comment: I checked it too.But doesn't working it to me@J.Shiv

Comment: db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE" +TABLE_NAME+ "(" + CODE + " INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT," + NAME + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY ," + TYPE + " TEXT," + ADD1 + " TEXT," + ADD2 + " TEXT," + CITY + " TEXT," + COUNTRY + " TEXT," + PHONENO + " TEXT," + CONTACTPERSON + " TEXT," + EMAILID + " VARCHAR(50)," + FAX + " REAL," + TNO +" REAL," + CSTNO + " REAL," + GSTNO + " REAL," + SERVICENO + " REAL)");

Comment: @Devika Try the above code ( from my previous comment)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add query like this:

```
String TABLE ="CREATE TABLE "+ TABLE_NAME + "("
                + CODE + " INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + NAME + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY ,"
                + TYPE + " TEXT,"
                + ADD1 + " TEXT,"
                + ADD2 + " TEXT,"
                + CITY + " TEXT,"
                + COUNTRY + " TEXT,"
                + PHONENO + " TEXT,"
                + CONTACTPERSON + " TEXT,"
                + EMAILID + " VARCHAR(50),"
                + FAX + " REAL,"
                + TNO + " REAL,"
                + CSTNO + " REAL,"
                + GSTNO+ " REAL,"                                                                                                                          
                + SERVICENO +" REAL" +")";

        db.execSQL(TABLE);
```

always care about white space and ending close bracts like above.
hope this will help you.

Comment: Still I am not getting @Nitesh Rathod