# No such column error in SQLITE database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am getting error as NO SUCH COLUMN in logcat and it is inserting properly
         How can I rectify this problem.Values which are given by me are representing correctly but SELECT query is not working for that values which are located in database table.

```
    String search = "select * from "+ TABLE_NAME +" Where PHONENO =" +num+ "                                         
           and NAME = "+name1+" and LASTNAME =" +lastname1;
           Cursor c = db.rawQuery(search,null);
           boolean res = c.moveToFirst();
         if (res) {
        String s1  = c.getString(0);
        String s2 = c.getString(1);
        String s3  = c.getString(2);
        String s4  = c.getString(3);
        String s5  = c.getString(4);
        String s6  = c.getString(5);
        String s7  = c.getString(6);
        String s8  = c.getString(7);
        String s9  = c.getString(8);
        String s10  = c.getString(9);
        String s11  = c.getString(10);
        String s12  = c.getString(11);
        String s13  = c.getString(12);
        String s14  = c.getString(13);
        String s15  = c.getString(14);
        String array[] ={s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8,s9,s10,s11,s12,s13,s14,s15};
        Intent i  = new Intent(this,SelectMember.class);
        i.putExtra("k1",array);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

**Logcat**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.user.database, PID: 9112
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: durga (code 1): , while compiling: select * from MASTER_ACCOUNTS Where PHONENO =8121680624 and NAME = durga and LASTNAME =veerepalli                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:887)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:498)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1255)
at com.example.user.database.Editoption.search(Editoption.java:36)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
Application terminated.
```

Comment: @Devika You should try String name=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("NAME")) instead of find column by its position

Comment: you have to specify the COLUMN Name

Comment: what are the column that not found ? It would be better if you show us how you created the table.

Comment: enclose your values in ' like `String search = "select * from "+ TABLE_NAME +" Where PHONENO ='" +num+ "'                                         
           and NAME = '"+name1+"' and LASTNAME ='" +lastname1 +"'";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String literals should be put in single quotes (`'`)

```
Where PHONENO ='" +num+ "' and NAME = '"+name1+"' and LASTNAME ='" +lastname1 +"'";
```

By the way, this will blow up when the value contains a quote. [Escape](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#sqlEscapeString(java.lang.String)) the string, or better use parameters.

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column:
> durga (code 1): , while compiling: select * from MASTER_ACCOUNTS Where
> PHONENO =8121680624 and NAME = durga and LASTNAME =veerepalli

**Rectify** Your Query first.

Informed you **[NO such table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43136655/error-as-no-such-table-while-inserting-data-in-to-table?answertab=active#tab-top).**

```
"SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_NAME +" WHERE PHONENO ='" +num+ "' AND NAME = '"+ name1 +"' AND LASTNAME ='" + lastname1 +"'";
```

Then **Uninstall old App** and **Clean-Rebuild-Run** .

Comment: This will blow up when the value contains a quote.

Comment: @CL. Sir . Would be happy if you rectify Query .

Comment: [Escape](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#sqlEscapeString(java.lang.String)) the string, or better use parameters.